# Testing Kendo Grid in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-grid

I'm trying to get my Karma tests working with the kendo grid in a brand new Angular project. The specs for this component look like

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RateTableProviderService } from "../_services/rate-table-provider.service";
import { RateTableComponent } from './rate-table.component';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Response, ResponseOptions } from "@angular/http";
import { IRateTableListViewModel } from "./models/IRateTableListViewModel";
import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';


describe('RateTableComponent', () => {
  let component: RateTableComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<RateTableComponent>;
  let observableSource = [
        {
          id: "3482cd2f-16f8-4d62-8d5d-d761de35e737",
          name: "Rate table 1",
          enabled: false,
          effectiveDate: new Date(),
          creditTierSetName: "",
          loanProducts: ""
        },
        {
          id: "3482cd2f-16f8-4d62-8d5d-d761de35e739",
          name: "Another rate table",
          enabled: false,
          effectiveDate: new Date(),
          creditTierSetName: "",
          loanProducts: ""
        }
      ];

  class MockRateTableProviderService extends RateTableProviderService {
    constructor() {
      super(null);
    }
    getRateTableData(): Observable<Array<IRateTableListViewModel>> {
      return Observable.from([observableSource]);
    }
  }
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    let mockRateTableProviderService = new MockRateTableProviderService();
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [RateTableComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: RateTableProviderService, useValue: mockRateTableProviderService }
      ],
      imports: [GridModule]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RateTableComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The tests run fine against chrome but in PhantomJS the tests hang.

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) RateTableComponent should be created FAILED
        Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

Everything works fine when running the tests against Chrome. I suspect that I'm not managing the asynchronous import when setting up the test bed correctly. If I pull out the kendo completely then the tests complete. I tried passing in a `done` call as part of the `beforeEach` but that also didn't work

```
beforeEach(async((done) => {
    let mockRateTableProviderService = new MockRateTableProviderService();
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [RateTableComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: RateTableProviderService, useValue: mockRateTableProviderService }
      ],
      imports: [GridModule]
    })
      .compileComponents().then(done);
  }));
```

Comment: I am getting this same error!

Comment: Same error here, found any workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining your fixture and component in the resolve of `.compileComponents()` as this will then be executed async as well as the setup of your testbed?

```
`.compileComponents.()
.then(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RateTableComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a second before each like so:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    let mockRateTableProviderService = new MockRateTableProviderService();
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [RateTableComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: RateTableProviderService, useValue: mockRateTableProviderService }
      ],
      imports: [GridModule]
    })
      .compileComponents().then(done);
 }));


beforeEach(() => {
  done();
}));
```

not as elegant as my main man simons answer above but should do the trick